# Howto make MCrypt and PHP work together on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, mcrypt

I've installed mcrypt on CentOS ( via yum ), but when I try to do a dl() call in A), I get the message in B).

- A) dl( mcrypt.so ) or die('The Mcrypt
  module could not be loaded ['.
  $prefix . 'mcrypt.' .
  PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX .']');
- B) The
  Mcrypt module could not be loaded [
  mcrypt.so ]

Now, I know that yum has installed mcrypt, but I don't know the location it has put it in. Can I find that out? More importantly, how can I get the latest installed mcrypt working with my PHP system. Many threads suggest you recompile PHP ( ex: http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=26527 ), but I don't know how to do this with CentOS. I've also played with my library paths to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Setup**

- **CentOS:**  Linux localhost.localdomain
  2.6.18-128.1.6.el5 #1 SMP Wed Apr 1 09:10:25 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64
  x86_64 GNU/Linux
- **mcrypt:**  mcrypt-2.6.8-1.el5.x86_64
- **PHP:**     php-5.1.6-23.2.el5_3.x86_64

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Do not use `dl` function it is deplecated in 5.3.0. And the questions is probably better to ask at serverfault.com.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot. Didn't realise that stackoverflow had branched out so much.

Comment: You should probably ask for a method that uses the build system of centos. This way you get a package that is installed (and maintained) the same way as the other packages in the repository, including dependencies. If you use "./configure,make,make install" the next update of the system might remove your changes or render them unusable without you knowing it until it's too late.

Answer (score 2):

Login as a root or Super User to the server and add the below commands

```
yum install php53-devel
yum install libmcrypt-devel
yum install gcc
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.3.tar.bz2
tar xvjf php-5.3.3.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.3/ext/mcrypt/
phpize
aclocal
./configure
make
make install
echo "extension=mcrypt.so" > /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini
service httpd restart
```

Reference [Install PHP 5.3 mcrypt extension on Centos 5.6](http://phpbugs.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/install-php-5-3-mcrypt-extension-on-centos-5-6/)

Comment: I had problems with mcrypt because libmcrypt-devel wasn't installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to assume there's some particular reason you can't use the package provided by the CentOS distributors (see [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/extras/i386/RPMS/php-mcrypt-5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1.i386.rpm), for one example.) I don't know CentOS, but I can give you a rough roadmap of the steps that would most likely lead to a successful build and install of the mcrypt module for PHP.

1. Get a copy of the PHP source that matches your distro's compiled version (CentOS may have a package for this)
2. Install the PHP development pacakges (probably something like "php5-dev") as well as all dependencies to build PHP for your distro (on Debian-based systems, this is done via `apt-get build-dep php5`, not sure the correct incantation for CentOS).
3. From the top level directory of the PHP source, cd into `ext/mcrypt`. In this directory, run `phpize` (this should have been installed alongside the afore-mentioned CentOS equivalent of `php5-dev`). This will generate a configure script in `ext/mcrypt` that will allow you to build mcrypt as a shared module.
4. From the same `ext/mcrypt` directory, issue `./configure --help` and look at the options available to you. From this point on, it's pretty much like any other Unix app: `configure`, `make`, `make install`.